# Is a function a derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, terminology

I'm reading introductory calculus and I find that 'function' tends to be defined by what it does rather than what it is. If $y = f(x)$, then surely the value of $y$ is dependent on that of $x$, i.e. *derived* from that of $x$; hence $y$ is a derivative and thus 'function of' equals 'derivative of'.

And yet the following chapters appear to deal with "derivative of a function", as if the word "derivative" is reserved for a particular type or phase of "derivation".

Can someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: All a _function_ is is a mapping that takes (in this case) a value for $x$ and returns another value $y$, where every value of $x$ has it's own _unique_ value for $y$ (think of the vertical line test). A _derivative_ usually refers to the rate of change of a function. Note that a derivative of a particular function can itself also be a function i.e

$$y = x^{2}$$

is a function and it's derivative

$$y' = 2x$$

is also a function in it's own right.

Comment: I think semantics is at issue here.  The word "derivative" literally means something that is based on something else.  In trading, a derivative is a financial transaction/contract the value of which is derived from the price of some underlying asset or non-traded factor (e.g., weather).  In physics, engineering, and mathematics it means something very specific.

Comment: "As if the word 'derivative' is reserved for a particular type or phase of 'derivation'". - Yes, that's right. (I hope that clears things up!) Mathematicians name things, and it's not always standard English use of the word.

Comment: @JonathanHebert Exactly.  Words can have multiple meanings.  And communities often create a language for facilitating communication internal to that community.

Comment: Essentially, if we use your convention for "derivative", then every object we already call a *function* will also be called a *derivative*. While mathematicians aren't especially afraid of redundancies (zeros and roots come to mind), the terminology "derivative" has a rather long history meaning something much more specific. We agree, as a community, to almost always use "derivative" in the calculus sense, as what's obtained from *differentiating* a function.

Answer (score 2):

A derivative *is* a function that is *derived* from another function, but take care not to miss out on the conceptual importance of the derivative as a *rate of change* as opposed to a simple derivation from another function.

---

Your issue seems to be primarily *notational* and *linguistic* rather than *conceptual*.

1. When you write "$y=f(x)$," what do you really mean? You almost never see something like $y=f(x)=x^2$; that is, $y$ and $f(x)$ denote the *same* thing and using them together like that would certainly be considered redundant.
2. Have you ever heard of a *mapping* by any chance? The words *function* and *mapping* are synonymous, but you will frequently encounter the latter word later down the road and for good reason: the mapping given by $f(x)=x^2$, for example, assigns to each real number $x$ the real number $x^2$. This is often communicated by writing something like, "Let the mapping $\alpha\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=x^2$." Hence, $\alpha$ is the name of the mapping that is *defined* by $f(x)=x^2$, where input values $x$ are turned into or "mapped to" the value $x^2$. This may sometimes be communicated by writing $x\mapsto x^2$ to indicate that $x^2$ is the *image* of $x$ under a mapping (in this case $\alpha$).
3. Your next issue seems to be with the linguistic interpretation of *derive* as opposed to *derivative*.

---

Here is how the *Oxford English Dictionary* defines *derivative* in the mathematical sense:

[image]

Hence, it would be more appropriate to say that a derivative is a function derived from another, but you need to make sure you are not missing the point of what a derivative actually *is* conceptually: the *rate of change* of a function, often expressed as a function itself (though you may consider the local rate of change rather than a moral global rate of change; even so, you could still use a function to describe this).

In this sense, the function $f'(x)=2x$ is the derivative of $f(x)=x^2$. Sure, $f'(x)$ is most certainly *derived* from $f(x)$, but you need to make sure you understand that what $f'(x)$ describes is the *rate of change* of $f(x)$ in a general sense.

Does that clear things up?

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for these generous and informative responses. I now understand that, to some extent, I was questioning mathematicians' "jargon". When I've done some more study/work and grasped concepts like "mapping" and "differential coefficient" I'll no doubt see even more clearly. Thanks again.